# Use NFC to connect android device to wifi without any 3rd party software

Tags: android, nfc

Is there a way to use nfc to connect an android device to a wifi network without the use of a 3rd party application. Ie using the built in functionality of android and how it reads nfc tags.

I need a nfc tag to connect the phone / device to a specific WiFi network and then download my application from that WiFi network. How can I go about doing this?

I can achieve this with an app such as nfc launcher, but then a user would have to go install that app then go and swipe the nfc tag to download my app.

So for a use case:

I want to have a nfc tag at a sales counter or restaurants table. Then all a user has to do to get and install the app is scan the qr code.

Comment: A NFC tag can't "connect" to Wifi itself without any device that carry the Internet...

Comment: So you are saying that android hasn't got built in support to connect the device to a certain wireless network. I need an application to read the nfc and then it will inturn connect to the wireless network>

Comment: `I need a nfc tag to connect to wifi and download my application` That's ambiguous, your question is non-sense for me.

Comment: While this questions is not worded properly, is actually makes sense. OP is talking about NFC>WiFi handover, a way to program NFC tag so that instead of entering WiFi connection params manually into your phone you could just touch that tag with your phone, and connection would be configured automatically.

I'm looking for similar function also, and appears that it's not possible at the moment.

Comment: Upvoting -- post-edit this seems like an entirely reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put a download link for your app on the NFC tag? If the device has an internet connection, tapping the tag will launch the browser (or the Google Play app) and follow the download link. It's not really up to you to demand that the device connects to a wifi network first.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer resolves my question with regards to opening the application. But with connecting to the network in the circumstance that I am developing for we do demand that they connect to a certain wifi connection as the application which the tag will be opening provides the user the service via the wifi network (which I want to connect to).

Comment: That sounds like information you should add to your question.

Answer (score 3):

I totally understand what you are trying to do here, and I am wanting to do the same thing myself.  The best info I have got so far comes from this post

[Share Wifi credentials via NFC tag without special apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081068/share-wifi-credentials-via-nfc-tag-without-special-apps)

However, whilst this tells us there is a specification for NFC>WiFi handover, it appears it is not supported by Android.

I will keep searching and let you know if I come up with anything further.

I'm also looking for NFC>Bluetooth handover, but coming across similar barriers :-(

Comment: So, it looks like this can absolutely be done, however it requires a 3rd party app to achieve it - which kind of defeats the object of the simplicity we are striving for!  I guess we need to wait until this kind of functionality is baked into Android/WinMob?

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question. Please take a look at the new NFC programmer provided by Google for devices >= Lollipop. I haven't delved into the details of this program myself but if there is a built-in support there, P2P tapping or tag read in order to program Wi-Fi details should get the slave peer device to obtain the required internet connection (simple WPA/WEP based SSID).

That way, when an internet connection is established, the slave could be instructed to download enabler apk from a remote source, such as PlayStore or internal private host server. However, PlayStore access would require that device be already equipped with a Google account (not possible on a factory reset device).

Comment: Also, this is interesting - http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/06/27/android-l-feature-spotlight-write-wi-fi-passwords-to-nfc-tags-directly-from-android/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve what these guys here provide:
https://www.tenonedesign.com/porter

You hold your NFC-capable andoid mobile to it and it connects to your wifi.
newer Iphones are shown a qr-code, SSID und password