# Connect to wifi using nfc

Tags: wifi, nfc

I am looking for a way to connect a NFC phone to my wifi (just using the built-in feature of NFC).

My current plan would be to push my wifi setting to the phone so that non-NFC phones can still connect to my wifi using a password.

My alternative plan was to use a NFC reader to get informations like mac address of a phone then add it to my list of approved mac addresses in my router.

What plan have the most chance of succeeding and how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The first plan sounds promising with the use of an app you can read the wifi credentials off the nfc http://lifehacker.com/six-sweet-things-you-can-do-with-nfc-1323120090
as answered here [Share Wifi credentials via NFC tag without special apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081068/share-wifi-credentials-via-nfc-tag-without-special-apps) its not supported to currently do this with out a nfc reading/dedicated nfc wifi app